# Why is the replace function removing part of my string?

Tags: string, vb.net

I'm not sure if I'm actually using VB.net. I'm using Visual Basic 2010 express, and I don't know if that's the same thing or not.

I'm using the replace function to replace a 0 at a specific position in a string with lots of 0s with a 1. I'm using the optional parameter that lets you choose where in the string the function starts searching for the character. But whenever it does this, it removes all the parts of the string before the position that I tell it to go to in the string.

So what can I do to make it return the entire string as it was before, but just with that one character changed at that position. The line of code is:

```
board = Replace(board, "0", "1", position, 1)
```

Comment: If you want to replace the character in one position, why not using mid?: `Mid(board,position,1)="1"`

Comment: Why not just: `board = board.Insert(0,"1")`

Comment: @Pikoh Thanks for editing my answer into your comment

Comment: @ProGrammer i'm sorry but my comment was before your answer. I just edited the replace part as i was thinking in c#. Anyway,what would be the point in copying your answer **in a comment**? Be cool man

Comment: @Pikoh Your comment that didn't actually compile was, yes

Comment: I'm not going to start a nonsense argue with you @ProGrammer. It's a pity  i can't access the editing history of a comment :)

Comment: To answer your OTHER hidden question.."I'm not sure if I'm actually using VB.net." You are actually using a limited version of Visual Studio with the VB part only. Visual Studio is a multi-language platform. The VB part is still vb.net in all of them.

Comment: @Patrick, I can see you're new here. Welcome. Consider taking the [tour] to get to know how things work round here. You've a few answers now. Have a look and look at accepting one should it work for you or should none of the answers work, provide more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some weird reason [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the string FROM position with N replacements.

From MSDN:

> The return value of the Replace function is a string that begins at the position specified by Start and concludes at the end of the Expression string, with the substitutions made as specified by the Find and Replace values.

But if you use a `StringBuilder`:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder(board)
sb = sb.Replace("0", "1", position, 1)
board = sb.ToString
```

It works as expected.

I have a sneaking suspicion that's a bug from Microsoft that they never fixed because it would impact all the people that were already using it that way.

Comment: thanks for the edit @Bugs  I'm still learning how to format stuff right.

Comment: Not a bug, but the designed behavior.  String.Replace inherited this functionality from the VB6 Replace function, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241892(v=vs.60).aspx.

Comment: Ya I know @MarkL but I have a feeling it is a very old error on MS part. Especially since they changed the way it works to what you would expect on the newer string-builder. Who in their right minds would intuitively expect a search and replace function to truncate from the index location. Unfortunately, if it was a mistake, it's one you can't fix without screwing up existing code. So it effectively became "A Feature"

Comment: Thanks, I'll use a string builder instead of the bug. I mean feature.

Comment: @Patrick, use the .ToString property of sb to get it back into board

Answer (score 0):

There is another method available which does what you need called `Mid` which you can read more about [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=vs.90).aspx).

It is used like so:

```
Mid(board, position, 1) = "1"
```

Be aware that "Start is one based"